# System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Update]

Tags: c#, json, httpclient, deserialize

Я пишу бота для телеграмма на C#-е
Я хочу чтобы при запуске кода, он писал мне Id и Username бота
Но при запуске пишет:
`` System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Update]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1. ``

Всё что я находил на сайтах было решением не моей проблемы, которое нельзя применить к моему коду

код:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text.Json;

using HttpClient client = new();

var updates = await ProcessAsync(client);

foreach (var upd in updates)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {upd.Id}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Username: {upd.Username}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

static async Task<List<Update>> ProcessAsync(HttpClient client)
{
    await using Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://api.telegram.org/bot(CENSORED)/getMe");
    var updates = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Update>>(stream);
    return updates ?? new();
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
public sealed record class Update(
    [property: JsonPropertyName("id")] string Id,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("username")] string Username){}
```

json:

```json
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": {
        "id": 6631136786,
        "is_bot": true,
        "first_name": "MoneySys",
        "username": "MoneySysBot",
        "can_join_groups": true,
        "can_read_all_group_messages": false,
        "supports_inline_queries": false
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, написано же, что в JSON нет подходящих данных, которые можно преобразовать в предложенный вами список. А чтобы понять, что там, надо видеть сам текст JSON. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте JSON. И почему вы решили, что там массив?

Comment: добавил json в вопрос

Comment: У вас в JSON объект внутри объекта. С какого перепугу вы пытаетесь распарсить это в список?

Comment: Ну и если вы **настолько** не понимаете что вообще делаете - зачем вы вообще пытаетесь делать сами? Возьмите библиотеку Telegram.Bot из NuGet

Comment: @PavelMayorov токсично же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В JSON

- `[]` - массив, коллекция
- `{}` - объект, запись

Вы пытаетесь объект распарсить как массив, отсюда и ошибка.

Как-то так получится:

```
public sealed record Response<T>(
    [property: JsonPropertyName("ok")] bool Ok,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("result")] T Result,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("description")] string Description
);
```

```
static Task<Response<T>> ProcessAsync<T>(HttpClient client)
{
    return client.GetFromJsonAsync<Response<T>>("https://api.telegram.org/bot(CENSORED)/getMe");
}
```

```
var response = await ProcessAsync<Update>(client);

if (response.Ok)
{
    var update = response.Result;

    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {update.Id}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Username: {update.Username}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(response.Description);
}
```